# DISABLE ARC still got Errors

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

i'm trying DISABLE ARC in some Facebook classes and still got Errors.

my steps was like that:

```
1) Build Settings:

      i Activated ARC=YES.

      Other linker flags = -ObjC -all_load
2) Build Settings>Compile Sources:

-fno-obj-arc  for All clases i want to disable ARC.
```

**after all that, i still gets an error build for all "release" in my project.
why? :/**

Comment: There's not nearly enough information here to help you. What's the actual error? Did it work at some point before? Are you upgrading an old project to ARC, or a new project with old libraries?

Comment: Do you have a typo in the `-fno-objc-arc` flag?

Comment: As an aside, isn't the [latest Facebook SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/ios/) ARC-compatible? I presume you must be working with an old project where you feel hesitant to upgrade.

Comment: i'm gets error build for all "release" lines 
Release codes marked in Red color.

Comment: @Ofir_Tel.Aviv Did you fix that typo? Or was that just in your post here, but did you get it right in your project? And, yes, if you have old the old Facebook SDK, you'll have those `release` statements, but certainly not in version 3.1.

Answer (score 3):

It's `-fno-objc-arc` to disable ARC, not `-fno-obj-arc`. I'm sure you don't need it, but see the [Use Compiler Flags to Enable and Disable ARC](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW15) in the *Transitioning to ARC Release Notes.*

I'd also encourage you to check out the latest [Facebook SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/ios/), if you can, which is ARC compatible.

Comment: yes, i didn't notice, i forgot to write it like that  -fno-objc-arc
Thank you everyone !!